# UITableView showing delete "-" dash on swipe to delete for cells out of view in other sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I am encountering what seems like a bug with swipe to delete for a UITableView, when I swipe to delete in a visible section it shows the red delete dash in some rows for sections out of view. This happens in IOS SDK 8.2.

Sorry, tried to post an image, but I don't seem to have enough reputation to post an image.

Please provide any thoughts on what could be causing this, Thanks.

**View Image** https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNCSJ.png

**Edited**

Code used is Standard UITableView Delegates and Datasource Delegates to enable Swipe to Delete.

```html
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if ((self.sectionForCellSwiped == indexPath.section) && self.rowForCellSwiped == indexPath.row) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }else{
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if (self.editEnabled) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        
        
        if ([self.DataSource numberOfForCategoryAtIndex:indexPath.section] == 1) {
            
            [self.DataSource removeItem:removedItem];
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
            
        }else{
            [self.DataSource removeItem:removedItem];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Comment: Added some code, pretty much using the standard Delegate methods. Thanks.

Comment: You can post a link of your image.

Comment: try to give border to your view of the cell

Comment: Thanks guys, I have added a link to the image. Additional thoughts?

Comment: @chiragshah Not sure I follow, how would I add a border to the cell?

Comment: @hh85 u can add border to cell "cell.contentview.layer.borderwidth = 1.0f and cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor black].CGColor"

Comment: @hh85 are you using custom cell? if yes, can u post your UItableViewCell code? did you try on accessoryView and editingAccessoryView properties of UItableViewCell?

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 I am using a custom cell, I will post it later today. I didn't use the accessoryview. If you look at the link to the image I added you will see exactly what is happening. Thanks